# Cannot open virtual machine in VMware Workstation

Tags: windows-7-x64, vmware-workstation

After I installed VMware Workstation(version 7) and tried to open OS X Mavericks.vmx give me this error:
Could not open virtual machine: C:\Users\developer4\Documents\FreeTorrentDownload\Downloads\OS X Mavericks 10.9 Retail VMware Image\OS X Mavericks 10.9 Retail VMware Image\OS X Mavericks 10.9 Retail VMware Image\OS X Mavericks\OS X Mavericks.vmx.

Internal error.

Why this error happened?

Answer (score 0):

This error occurred because there is something wrong with the VM image. Create your own VM and install from the OSX disk or image.

Comment: I downloaded OS X Mavericks 10.9 Retail VMware Image about 7 giga byte , what is the wrong with it?  and how to create my own VM?

Answer (score 0):

this question is from long time ago but it may help others :I guess this would solve your problem: go `Run` thne type `services.msc` then `Start` `Vmware Authorization service`.